# Why does the learning rate influence whether i get a error from BCE or not?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, learning-rate, torch

When I use a learning rate higher than 0.001, I get this:

```
Assertion `input_val >= zero && input_val <= one` failed.
```

This means that the input I gave to BCE is above 1 or below 0 right? Why does changing the learning rate cause this error? Also, I am passing the input through a sigmoid activation function before passing it to the BCE so it should be between 0 and 1.